# Passing a multi-method object to another class

Tags: c#, object, methods, refactoring, wrapper

As part of a personal project I am working on I took a small codebase written by another programmer and was trying to refactor it to my own purposes. Long story short, they had this huge section of code that was an incoming command parser. I moved the code to it's own class file and moved several code bits to their own methods in that class. The problem I'm encountering is that I can't pass two needed objects from the original block of code to the new parser class. The orginal code section uses an mutliple-method object called AllSockets. I can't seem to figure out how to pass this object to the new class method without getting the error

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'

The invoking line of code:

```
bool wasValidCommand = (commandParser.CheckForCommands(thisConnection, AllSockets, characterPath, helpFilePath));
```

The method invoked:

```
public bool CheckForCommands(ConnectionInfo _connected, object _AllSockets, string characterPath, string helpFilePath)
```

I've posted the hosting Server.cs class here: http://codepad.org/1kRHA1nk

The new class I am trying to pass the object to is here: http://codepad.org/oONRaEtt

Warning: The code is really hacked together right now and variable naming is a nightmare. I can paste the specific sections if that would be easier to read. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  AllSocket method is declared as

```
public object AllSockets(string tempFlag, object objectOne, object object_Two, object object_Three)
```

From a quick look over the code, it appears AllSockets is used in the private Shout(..) method of the class - as method. So in order to pass this as a function object, you may declare the CheckForCommands method with a parameter of type delegate or Function:

```
delegate object AllSocketDelegate (string tempFlag, object objectOne, object object_Two, object object_Three); 
public bool CheckForCommands(ConnectionInfo _connected, AllSocketDelegate _AllSockets, string characterPath, string helpFilePath)
```

or similar with the Func instead of a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `object _AllSockets` with:

```
Func<string, object, object, object, object>_AllSockets
```

You should probably replace this in CheckForCommands, Shout and Tell method signatures.

Comment: Very interesting. I had not been aware of Func and now have something new to study. It fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

`AllSockets` is a method. I'm guessing you want to take the object that the `AllSockets` method returns and pass that into the `commandParser.CheckForCommands` function.

Try something like:

```
object allSockets = AllSockets(...);
bool wasValidCommand = (commandParser.CheckForCommands(thisConnection, allSockets, characterPath, helpFilePath));
```

Comment: this would not work, since the AllSockets parameter is later in the method used like a function.